# Meaning of the syntax: return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()

Tags: c#, syntax

In the C# code below, I found the usage of `_()` strange. Can anyone explain what this means?

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

    return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The code might be more easily understood by inserting a line break after the `return` statement:

```
return _();

IEnumerable<TSource> _()
{
    var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            yield return element;
    }
}
```

In this context, the underscore is just an arbitrary name for a [*local function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions) (which is a new feature introduced in C# 7.0). If you prefer, you could replace the underscore by a more descriptive name:

```
return DistinctByHelper();

IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctByHelper()
{
    var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            yield return element;
    }
}
```

As a local function, the _ (or DistinctByHelper) method can access all the variables of the `DistinctBy` method.

By the way, the reason for having two methods here is so that, in case any argument is null, `ArgumentNullException` will be thrown immediately when `DistinctBy` is called instead of when the result is enumerated (due to the presence of the `yield return` statement).

Comment: I *really* hope this pattern doesn't catch on.  That's just ugly.

Comment: I never liked how local functions lack any kind of identifying keyword - they're easily confused for a local delegate or object initialiser list, for example. A simple `func` keyword or mandatory lambda syntax `=>` would help).

Comment: The local function seems unnecessary here anyway.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions) give two examples for why a local function like this might be used. Mainly so exceptions are thrown when created instead of when iterated/awaited.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the use for it; Making it local saved some keystrokes by making use of closures, and protects the function within its scope.  My main complaint is naming it `_`.

Comment: Agreed. The underscore name + starting the definition on the same line doesn't sit well with me.